# Rails send to view information from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm newer in Ruby on Rails, and i can't understand how to notify or send to view some information form controller. Here is code =>

```
  def index
    @post = Post.all()

    #here i want notify new_post_view about Post's empty
    if @post.length == 0
      redirect_to new_post_path
    end

  end
```

how i can do this??

Comment: flash[:notice] = "No posts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  if @posts.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "No posts found"
    redirect_to(new_post_path) 
  end
end
```

In your layout template:

```
<p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
```

Comment: how i understand in `new_post` posts is empty?

Comment: You could set a `flash` message that is displayed when the `new` view renders. Will update answer.

Comment: thanks, it's helped, you know best tutorials to understanding ruby & rails

Comment: I always keep the [Railsguides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html), [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and the [Ruby API Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) open. Buy a Rails book and spend ten bucks on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/).